# How to solve : ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I am trying to drop a tablespace as

```
drop tablespace HC0974888012317 including contents and datafiles cascade CONSTRAINTS;
```

I am getting this error

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01555: snapshot
>   too old: rollback segment number 0 with name "SYSTEM" too small

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972979/snapshot-too-old-error) helps. Are you dropping while something is still creating sessions and modifying data in tablespace?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error before. I solved it by using this.

Open the database and enter these commands.

```
 SQL> startup mount 
 SQL> alter session set events '10015 trace name adjust_scn level 1'; 
 SQL> alter database open resetlogs;
```

I hope it will solve the problem.